# Problem with regex creation if excape character is at the end of the parameter value

Tags: java, regex

I get three parameters in a string. Each parameter is written in the form: Quotes, Name, Quotes, Equals sign, Quotes, Text, Quotes. The parameter separator is a space.
Example 1:

```
"param1"="Peter" "param2"="Harald" "param3"="Marie"
```

With java.util.regex.Matcher I can find any name and text by the following regex:

```
"([^"]*)"\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
```

Now, however, there may be a quotation mark in the text. This is masked by a backslash.
Example 2:

```
"param1"="Peter" "param2"="Har\"ald" "param3"="Marie"
```

I have built the following regex:

```
"([^"]*)"\s*=\s*("([^"]*(\\")*[^"]*)*[^\\]")
```

This works well for example 2, but is not a universal solution.

If the backslash is at the end of a parameter-value, the solution does not work anymore.
Example 3:

```
"param1"="Peter" "param2"="Harald\" "param3"="Marie"
```

If the backslash is at the end of the value, the matcher interprets "Harald\" " as the value of parameter 2 instead of "Harald\".

Do you have a universal solution for this problem? Thanks in advance for your input.

Kind regards
Dominik

Comment: This is done with `"([^"]*)"\s*=\s*("[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*")`, see https://regex101.com/r/d4Wu3k/1

Comment: Where is closing quote in `"param2"="Harald\"` ?

Comment: Hello anubhava: In param2 the value is Harald\
The Backslash-Sign is the end of the internal String

Comment: Hello Wiktor: this helps a bit, but Example 3 doesn't work with it.

Comment: The expression of the parameter values come from an external source. This source masks quotes with a backslash. However, the backslash itself is not masked. I think this is a logical problem. A masking character must also be masked with itself if it is included in the string.

Comment: Reopening because this question is not just about escaping, e.g. `"param2"="Harald\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in Java:

```
\"([^\"]*)\"\h*=\h*(\"[^\\\"]*(?:\\(?=\"(?:\h|$))|(?:\\.[^\\\"]*))*\")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IJ0yY5/2)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `\"([^\"]*)\"`: Match quoted string a parameter name
- `\h*=\h*`: Match `=` surrounded with optional spaces
- `(`: Start capture group #1
- `\"`: Match opening `"`
- `[^\\\"]*`: Match 0 or more of non-quote, non-backslash characters
- `(?:`:

  - `\\`: Match a `\`
  - `(?=\"(?:\h|$))`: Must be followed by a `"` that has a whitespace or line afterwards
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?:\\.[^\\\"]*))*`: Match an escaped character followed by 0 or more of non-quote, non-backslash characters
- `\"`: Match closing `"`
- `)`: End capture group #1